# Want to create google map navigation in my application - custom way

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, location-client

I have created an application in which I am trying to show user's movement by animating marker position.

1. Using Google map V2.
2. Location updates using location client.
3. Animating marker using new location.

But comparing with Google map navigation, there is no continuity in rendering navigation.

Can anyone suggest a better approach? Thanks!

Comment: You want a steadily moving marker(position)?

Comment: Yeah. Jus like google map default navigation

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13728041/move-markers-in-google-map-v2-android) is what you looking for.

Comment: Yes. That helped. But currently when we compare it with google map(After mocking a path). In my app marker is not moving in exact path there is a slight shift.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For continuity, I think you need to fetch regular location updates from location client by giving location request like this.

```
LocationRequest request = LocationRequest.create()
                .setInterval(0).setFastestInterval(0)
                .setSmallestDisplacement(0)
                .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
```

Then for smooth animation you can follow the approach Steve Benett mentioned. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13728041/move-markers-in-google-map-v2-android)

The last case you mentioned in the comment about the path. I also had the same issue in one of my app. I tried with gps route simulator app to mock a route. then comparing my app and google map, googlemap followed the correct road path while my app's marker was moving slightly shifted from road. Then I tried some tweaks with marker. Like this

```
mPositionMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .flat(true)
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                        .fromResource(R.drawable.positionIndicator))
                .anchor(0.5f, 0.5f)
                .position(
                        new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location
                                .getLongitude())));
```

This worked for me. This positioned my marker on same location as of google map. (Depends on the accuracy of location though).

Thanks for the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14826345/android-maps-api-v2-change-mylocation-icon)

Comment: [LocationClient](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationClient.html) is deprecated. Look at this answer for current options: [LocationManager or Location Service API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24266362/android-google-maps-api-location/27195920#27195920).